# XSLT - convert Date from any format into a specific format

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a date value in a field in XML file in this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="nightlyRate/@date" />
```

I want to convert it into a given format:

```
<xsl:param name="dateformat" select="yyyy/mm/dd">
```

How can I do that in my XSL transform?

Comment: There is no way to convert a "date in any format"  to a known format. You must know the format in advance. If the input is "YYYY-MM-DD" **and** you're using XSLT 2.0, then you can use the `format-date()` function to format it. Otherwise you need to manipulate it using string functions.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some smart way of knowing whether 03/04/1920 represents 4th March or 3rd April, the problem is impossible.

Before you start writing code in XSLT or any other language, you need a clear specification of what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

In **XSLT 1.0**, there is no function (as *@michael.hor257k* said) which converts date in specific format.

You can achieve it specifically in following two ways based on your environment:

**1.** If you are using java, you can write Util classes using **java.util.TimeZone** & **java.util.Calendar** API.

Define final static constants in util class and parse the value into required date format using these APIs.

**2.** Assuming you have input source like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
    <nightlyRate date="20180312" />
</Root>
```

Then the xslt to transform it will use simple `substring()` function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <date>
        <xsl:call-template name="getFormattedDate">
            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="Root/nightlyRate/@date" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </date>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="getFormattedDate">
    <xsl:param name="date" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($date,1,4),'/',substring($date,5,2),'/',substring($date,7,2))" />
</xsl:template>
```

In **XSLT 2.0**,

Taking the same input source, it can be written as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="dateString">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(Root/nightlyRate/@date,1,4)" />
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(Root/nightlyRate/@date,5,2)" />
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(Root/nightlyRate/@date,7,2)" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <RequiredFormat>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-date(xs:date($dateString), '[Y]/[M]/[D]')" />
    </RequiredFormat>
    <OtherFormat>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-date(xs:date($dateString), '[MNn] [D], [Y]')" />
    </OtherFormat>
</xsl:template>
```

And the **output** will be:

```
<RequiredFormat>2018/3/12</RequiredFormat>
<OtherFormat>March 12, 2018</OtherFormat>
```

Comment: @michael.hor257k : My bad. I am habituated to use it due to my own projects. There is no need here using it. Thanks.